# How to create a completely unique number set in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a `perl` script that creates a complete set of unique, random numbers.

let's say I have numbers `1` to `50` I want to create `5` sets with `5` unique numbers per set, but not repeating a number in any set. The below script does generate the numbers randomly and unique per line, but numbers are repeated in the other lines. So the **current result** will be something like:

```
20  11  28   5  10
 5  23  20  42  14
 1  38   6   7   9
25   0  16  35  17
23   0  42   5   8
```

As the above result demonstrates, numbers `5`, `0` and `23` etc. were repeated. I actually want to completely exclude `0`s and not repeat a single number. The below **expected** result demonstrates the desired output.

```
 2  20  12  15  9
19  10  42  13  3
 7  38  50   1 33
 6  22  49   4 21
48   8  25  11  3
```

The above does not have `0` and no numbers are repeated.

Here is my current script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for (1..5) {
my @numbers;
my %unique;

for (1..5) {
    my $number = int rand(50);
    redo if $unique{$number}++;
    push @numbers, $number;
 }
 print join('  ', @numbers), "\n";
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any possible assistance and sincerely hope that my question is understandable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the declaration of `%unique` outside the first loop, and it'll work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my %unique;
for ( 1 .. 5 ) {
   my @numbers;

   for ( 1 .. 5 ) {
      my $number = int rand(49) + 1;
      redo if $unique{$number}++;
      push @numbers, $number;
   }
   print join( "\t", @numbers ), "\n";
}
```

By declaring it inside the loop, you create a new one each time, so numbers will only be unique per line.

Your other problem is - you seem not to want `0` in the mix - so you actually just need to add 1 to everything.

You could also use `List::Util`s `shuffle` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw ( shuffle );

my @pick_list = shuffle( 1 .. 50 );

for ( 1 .. 5 ) {
   print join "\t", splice( @pick_list, 0, 5 ), "\n";
}
```

Comment: By the wise words of Homer Simpson. __DOH!__ I actually had the `%unique` declaration before the loop at one stage, but funny enough I never checked the results when I ran it to see if it will fix the issue. The second option however is better for me as I can then eliminate the `0`. Thanks very much.

Comment: oh wait, I see you added `+1` at `my $number` which also eliminates the `0` :). Thanks again.

Comment: It's not very important, but you might want to add parenthesis (around `join`'s arguments) to remove the `\t` before each `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to keep testing for uniqueness: the usual way to select multiple random non-repeating subsets from a list of values is to `shuffle` that list first. Then the subsets can be taken from the list without replacement to achieve the desired result

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'shuffle';

my @list = shuffle 1 .. 50;

print join("\t", splice @list, 0, 5), "\n" for 1 .. 5;
```

#### output

```
36  18  14  32  22
6   38  1   19  33
27  9   45  34  12
26  49  10  43  37
28  8   21  39  11
```